# OSGi MANIFEST.MF files browser

Tags: maven, osgi, manifest.mf

We're developing a big application using osgi (felix, spring-dm, maven-plugin).
I'd like to add to the doc a complete graph of all dependencies (import/export from each bundle).
This is both for documentation and to double check if there are wrong versions or incompatible requirement somewhere.

Is there a tool that would go across all the bundle (in jar format) get the manifest file and display the graph? or at least produce a complete list of all the required bundles?

In case it doesn't exist do you think it would be a good idea for us to write it ourselves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a thing already exists for Eclipse with PDE ... the [blog post here shows a generic PDE solution](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/04/13/visualizing-osgi-systems/) and [the other here shows the Spring Tool Suite solution](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/03/05/osgi-development-tools-in-sts/).

[image: Graph Plug-in dependencies view from the generic PDE solution]

Install URL: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/pde/incubator/visualization/site/

Project page: http://www.eclipse.org/pde/incubator/dependency-visualization/index.php

See also [post here for instructions for the generic PDE solution](http://blog.ianbull.com/2007/08/pde-dependency-view-soc.html):

1. Show View -> Plug-in Development -> Graph Plug-in dependencies
2. Right-Click in the view -> select Focus-on
3. Select a Plug-in using Eclipse' standard plugin chooser
4. enjoy